# Significant Performance Difference in Delete using Derived Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to delete large amounts of data from a table that is a vendor design. It is over-indexed and any update/insert/deletes are painful. Removing NC indexes is not available to me.
I am testing different ways to delete the data in batches. I discovered today that the below statement is considerably faster when I do not use a variable to hold the date. Why would this make such a difference? Use of TempDB? Do you have a better solution you would be willing to share? Performance is even worse when explicitly typed date is replaced with getdate().

```
--example 1:
--very slow
declare @cleanday as datetime
select @cleanday = dateadd(day,-60,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CAST('2013-12-22' as datetime))))

delete ES1
from ( select top (10000) es.id1 from es where 
                        es.ID2 in 
                        (
                        21,
                        20,
                        19,
                        151
                        )                       
                        and es.DateCreated < @cleanday
                        order by es.id1
                  ) ES1

--example 2:
--much faster

delete ES1
       from ( select top (10000) es.id1 from es where  
                        es.ID2 in 
                        (
                        21,
                        20,
                        19,
                        151
                        )                       
                        and es.DateCreated < dateadd(day,-60,CAST('2013-12-22' as datetime))
                        order by es.id1
                  ) ES1
```

Comment: 'DELETE' statement got clipped on my top example when i pasted.

Comment: read them both with the delete from. my apologies in bad clipboard form.

Comment: Did you look at the query plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Some Test Data  */
CREATE TABLE Stats_Test_Table (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), VALUE INT)
GO
DECLARE @i INT = 1
WHILE (@i <= 100)
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Stats_Test_Table
    VALUES (@i)
    SET @i = @i + 1;
 END
GO

/* 
Execute the following command to flush any executiong plan already
existing in your chache
**WARNING**
 DO NOT execute this command on your production server as it will 
 flush all the created execution plan for all the queries.

 I guess you are doing all this on a test server anyway.
*/
-- Clear cache 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO

/* 
Four Queries with exactly the same syntax only difference is 
for 1st Two queries I have Hardcoded the value in WHERE clause

for last two queries I have used an INT parameter in WHERE clause
 */


--Query 1 with Hardcoded value in WHERE clause
SELECT * 
FROM Stats_Test_Table
WHERE ID = 50;
GO
--Query 2 with Hardcoded value in WHERE clause
SELECT * 
FROM Stats_Test_Table
WHERE ID = 51;
GO

--Query 3 with Variable @ID_1 value in WHERE clause
DECLARE @ID_1 INT;
SET @ID_1 = 52;
SELECT * 
FROM Stats_Test_Table
WHERE ID = @ID_1;
GO
--Query 4 with Variable @ID_2 value in WHERE clause
DECLARE @ID_2 INT;
SET @ID_2 = 52;
SELECT * 
FROM Stats_Test_Table
WHERE ID = @ID_2;
GO


/*
Now execute the following statement to get all the cached execution plans
remeber once you have cleared you CACHE memory  with the DBCC command
you will have to execute all the above queries and the following one as soon
as because sql server is constantly executing queries behind the scense but we
dont see them. so the longer you take more results you will have in your result
set of the following query.
*/

-- Query DMVs for execution plan reuse statistics

SELECT  stats.execution_count AS [Execution_Count]
       ,p.size_in_bytes       AS [Size]
       ,[sql].[text]          AS [plan_text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans p
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) sql
JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats stats
ON stats.plan_handle = p.plan_handle
ORDER BY [plan_text]
```

**Cached Execution Plans**

```
╔═════════════════╦═══════╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Execution_Count ║ Size  ║                                                                     plan_text                                                                     ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║               1 ║ 40960 ║   --Query 3 with Variable @ID_1 value in WHERE clause  DECLARE @ID_1 INT;  SET @ID_1 = 52;  SELECT *   FROM Stats_Test_Table  WHERE ID = @ID_1;   ║
║               2 ║ 32768 ║ (@1 tinyint)SELECT * FROM [Stats_Test_Table] WHERE [ID]=@1                                                                                        ║
║               1 ║ 40960 ║ --Query 4 with Variable @ID_2 value in WHERE clause  DECLARE @ID_2 INT;  SET @ID_2 = 52;  SELECT *   FROM Stats_Test_Table  WHERE ID = @ID_2;     ║
╚═════════════════╩═══════╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I executed four queries in total. let say Q1 , Q2 , Q3 and Q4. Sql server has created 3 execution plans for me.

**Query 1 and 2**

`(@1 tinyint)SELECT * FROM [Stats_Test_Table] WHERE [ID]=@1`

> Now if you look closer at the result set of above query Sql Server
>   created One Execution plan for Q1 and reused it for Q2. Both had a
>   hardcoded value in the where clause.
>
> The execution plan with Execution_Counts 2 has a variable appended to
>   it  **=@1** . It is called Auto Parametrization. Sql Server adds a
>   parameter to an execution plan and reuses it for next execution.

**Query 3 and 4**

> Now for Query 3 and 4 we have two separate execution plans. Even
>   though both queries and somewhat same but this time sql server decided
>   to not to use the same execution plan and created a new one for each
>   query.

**Conclusion**

> When query is passed a parameter instead of a hardcoded value sql
>   server will create a new execution plan each time the query is
>   executed.
>
> In your case you in 1st Query you passed a parameter and in second
>   query you passed a hardcoded value therefore 2nd query is faster then
>   the 1st one :).

Answer (score 0):

By moving the where clauses (or equivalent) to/from a variable vs. hard coded values you can often see a difference in performance due to the query optimizator. I.e., when hard code the optimizer may recognize that use a particular index would be optimal

Sometimes you can get a big advantage by changing the isolation level, especially if you can stop deleting data in batches with an order by when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink it.  Just use TOP in your delete: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175486%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Example:

```
DELETE TOP 10000 FROM Table01
```

There are stipulations about random or ordered deletes (you must specify an ORDER BY clause).  Depending on what you want to do and how you want to do it, this may accomplish what you want with relatively little work.